# PHP nested array in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to do a simple nested array in a session variable. But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic for the dynamic creation of the arrays.

What I think my code should look like (which I know is wrong, because I want it to be dynamic):

Page 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = array();
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'][0] = array('name' => 'john smith', 'age' => '20', 'city' => 'new york');
$_SESSION['test'][1] = array('name' => 'jane doe', 'age' => '42', 'city' => 'seattle');
```

I want to be able to do a foreach loop to grab the values

```
foreach($_SESSION['test'] as $test){
echo "Name " . $test['name'];
echo "Age " . $test['age'];
echo "City " . $test['city'];
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to be dynamic? Are you fetching data from a database?

Comment: To make it dynamic, use `[]` without an index to append new rows:  `$_SESSION['test'][] = array(....);` There's a note about appending [in the Arrays manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think that's what I'm looking for. Let me go test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push to an array like so:

```
// don't include the index, just use []
$_SESSION['test'][] = array('name' => 'john smith', 'age' => '20', 'city' => 'new york');
```

Or using [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
array_push($_SESSION['test'], array('name' => 'john smith', 'age' => '20', 'city' => 'new york'));
```